# Different display name of field depending on page layout

Tags: page-layout

how do I set different display names for a single field in multiple page layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to accomplish this would be to create a formula field for unique display name. This won't scale though, so if there are more than a few different display names you will need to find a real solution.

The display name of a field should be descriptive of the data the field contains, and if that data means something different to different users you should rethink the name that was given to the field initially and try to come up with something more abstract that would be sufficiently descriptive to your users.

Comment: This solutios will work only for Read - Only fields. If it is input type field, then it will not work

Comment: thank you so much! creating a new vf page, etc would take so much time just to change a single label. this would be good for now.